# PyInstaller executable is not working if using multiprocessing in pyqt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I was working in my project related to pyqt5 GUI. I used **multiprocessing** to make it faster. When I run my program in editor, it works fine.
But when I converted my program into executable using **pyinstaller**, then while running the program through this executable, it's not working.
GUI opens, but close once it comes to the multiprocessing portion of the code (I get to know this by putting some print statement)

I have also tried `mutiprocessing.freeze_support()`, still it's not worked.

if I remove the multiprocessing, program through executable works fine, But I need to use multiprocessing to make it faster.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. You need to provide more information, i.e. your code for us to provide any help. Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: That's the trickiest question ever, just make sure that only the main process is calling qt, and by make sure, i mean understanding the entire implementation of multiprocessing on your os and how all functions related to qt and multiprocessing work on your os in order to be absolutely certain, or you'll run into segmentation fault ...... or just spare yourself and don't use multiprocessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem a while ago, and I recommend using [Nuitka](https://nuitka.net) hence it supports Multiprocessing. If the problem lasts, try to use the `threading` library:

```py
from threading import Thread
def worker(a,b):
    while True:
        print(a+b)
        a+=1
my_thread = Thread(target = worker, args = [10,20])
my_thread.start()
```

You can also setup a class if you want to terminate the thread at a certain point.